# Modified 3x2 Plate with Rubber Bristle Bottom and snap-on cover?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I've had this odd little part laying around my desk for some time - does anyone know what it is?  There's no Lego logo anywhere, and I've searched BrickLink somewhat comprehensively, so I'm guessing it's from a compatible set.

It's a modified 3x2 plate, but without a hole, and the red bottom part is sort of a rubbery, grippy substance.  The "cover" is softer, non-ABS plastic, and can snap onto the plate either way.

I'm guessing it came from my wife's nephews in a whole pile of stuff they gave us - mostly Lego but there was some MegaBloks stuff mixed in too.  Probably not from after 2000 at the very latest.

[image: Top View]
[image: Top View Cover Removed]
[image: Bottom View]
[image: Bottom View Cover Removed]

Comment: Definitely not LEGO. Part with red insert seem to represent a brush. Do both pieces come apart easily?

Comment: The two pieces are not difficult to get apart - it's clear the one is supposed to be a "cover" for the red part of the other.  The red stuff is a rubbery substance - like it was supposed to provide traction or something.

Comment: Is it not normal to close the newer question as a dup of the older one (granted the quality is about the same)?

Answer (score 5):

So, the curiosity bug bit me again.  The mysterious part appears to be a Kre-O "Motion Brick" which appeared in various sets. In my research I found that there is a variation (hollow vs. solid) in the studs, as shown in the picture.
[image]