# 2x2 plate with round section and rubber bristles?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Very strange piece with soft rubber bristles. Bought in a misc box from a garage sale for my son and daughter.

[image]

Comment: You're not the first to ask, but that question has no answer, so I can't mark this as a duplicate: [Modified 3x2 Plate with Rubber Bottom and snap-on cover?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10880/modified-3x2-plate-with-rubber-bottom-and-snap-on-cover)

Answer (score 6):

So, the curiosity bug bit me again.  The mysterious part appears to be a Kre-O "Motion Brick" which appeared in various sets. In my research I found that there is a variation (hollow vs. solid) in the studs, as shown in the picture.
[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I have found out her Kre o blocks in the mix. My son kept asking me what it was and I had no idea! Thanks again!